# apiVersion is not the same as in the helm template

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, minikube, consul

I'm using [consul helm chart repo](https://github.com/hashicorp/consul-helm) to install consul agent. I'm installing the chart on my minikube cluster (version 1.10).
The template of the daemonSet for consul client shows apiVersion: [apps/v1](https://github.com/hashicorp/consul-helm/blob/master/templates/client-daemonset.yaml#L3).
When i'm installing consul and checking the apiVersion I get a different version:

```
❯ kubectl edit ds consul-agent-consul

apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
```

I can't seem to understand why is that?
When i'm running helm install in dry-run mode I see the correct api version:

```
❯ helm install consul-agent . --debug --dry-run
# Source: consul/templates/client-daemonset.yaml
# DaemonSet to run the Consul clients on every node.
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: DaemonSet
```

using helm version:

```
❯ helm version                                                                                                                                                                                                                         
version.BuildInfo{Version:"v3.2.4", GitCommit:"0ad800ef43d3b826f31a5ad8dfbb4fe05d143688", GitTreeState:"dirty", GoVersion:"go1.14.3"}
```

Edit:
kubectl version:

```
Client Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"16+", GitVersion:"v1.16.6-beta.0", GitCommit:"e7f962ba86f4ce7033828210ca3556393c377bcc", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2020-01-15T08:26:26Z", GoVersion:"go1.13.5", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"darwin/amd64"}
Server Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"10", GitVersion:"v1.10.0", GitCommit:"fc32d2f3698e36b93322a3465f63a14e9f0eaead", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2018-03-26T16:44:10Z", GoVersion:"go1.9.3", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"}
```

Comment: share output of kubectl version

Comment: added to my question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Kubernetes API Server version is `1.10.0` and kubectl client version is 1.16. Before Kubernetes API Server version `1.16` `DaemonSet` were in `extensions/v1beta1` which was changed to `apps/v1` in Kubernetes API Server version `1.16`. You should upgrade Kubernetes API Server version to 1.16 or later if you want to use `DaemonSet`  with `apps/v1`

Comment: I'm using minikube latest version which is 1.10. Can I upgrade the api server in minikube to 1.16?
Also when running `kubectl api-versions` to see what supported versions my api server has I see: `apps/v1`

Comment: latest version of Minikube is 1.11...Upgrade kubectl 1.18  and Minikube to 1.11